# Unable to verify my domain for letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, domain, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I can't understand how to verify my domain for letsencrypt.

```
$ ./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/my_user1/my_domain -d my_domain.com -d www.my_domain.com
Requesting root privileges to run certbot...
  /home/my_user1/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/my_user1/my_domain -d my_domain.com -d www.my_domain.com
Failed authorization procedure. my_domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://my_domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/aaa: "<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>", www.my_domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.my_domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/bbbb: "<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: my_domain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://my_domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/aaaaa:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   Domain: www.my_domain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.my_domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/bbbb:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

After that I create those 2 files in acte-challenge directory, re-run the script and but this time it requests 2 different ones. That is, it's always step ahead and can't know what files it'll generate next time.

What should I do about that?

Comment: First, update to the current version of certbot.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, it's the latest one already.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

> Requesting root privileges to run certbot...

and the <kbd>$</kbd> in `$ ./letsencrypt-auto` seem to indicate that you're trying to run letsencrypt as an unprivileged user.

> [**System Requirements**](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#system-requirements)
>
> The Let’s Encrypt Client ... **requires root access** in order to write to `/etc/letsencrypt`, `/var/log/letsencrypt`, `/var/lib/letsencrypt`; to bind to ports `80` and `443` (if you use the standalone plugin) and to read and modify webserver configurations (if you use the apache or nginx plugins).

Cert-bot is slightly more forgiving, but will need [additional parameters](https://certbot.eff.org/faq/#does-certbot-require-root-administrator-privileges) when you don't run it as root:

> The webroot and manual plugins work well without root privileges. However, you need to provide writable paths for Certbot’s working directories either by ensuring that `/etc/letsencrypt/`, `/var/log/letsencrypt/`, `/var/lib/letsencrypt/` are writable, or by picking different directories with the **`--config-dir`, `--logs-dir`**, and **`--work-dir`** flags.